# Generate auto increment number in a textbox using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to add sequence numbers in textbox but the format is 001 to onward, the main problem is when the number comes to 009, after it became 0010, four digit character. I want to reduce a zero from it, the number should look like 010. Please help me for this problem

Answer (score 2):

This should meet your needs.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:000}", i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty. Probably not the best way to do this:

```
textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text) + 1).ToString();
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1)
{
   textBox1.Text = "00" + textBox1.Text;
}
else if (textBox1.Text.Length == 2)
{
   textBox1.Text = "0" + textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: it helps me,thanx.But i want last insert number in table from database,i mean that max(id) from table